# CSS overflow: auto in some elements don't work

Tags: html, ios, css, overflow, swipe

I have Ios mobile app and using WebKit Safari. I have an container with items. Container must swipe up/down. Elements inside container - left/right. The problem is, when i set overflow: auto; to both - and container and elements, when i swipe elements - they works. But if i want swipe the hole container (up/down), it don't. I need to swap elements and container too Please help!

[image]

```
<div id="container">
         <div id="data-container">
              <div class="left-right">
                  <div class="some-content"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="left-right">
                  <div class="some-content"></div>
              </div>
              <div class="left-right">
                  <div class="some-content"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>




#container{
   height: 100px;
   width: 200px;
}
#data-container{
   height: 500px;
   width: 200px;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
.left-right{
   height: 50px;
   width: 300px;
   overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing I think I found a solution to what you mean.
Here the `green` elements move left and right, and the whole `red` container moves up and down.

```css
    #container {
      background: blue;
      height: 100px;
      width: 200px;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    #data-container {
      background: red;
      height: 500px;
      width: 200px;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    .left-right {
      background: green;
      overflow-x: auto;
    }
    .some-content {
      width: 300px;
      height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="data-container">
    <div class="left-right">
      <div class="some-content">LEFT-RIGHT A</div>
    </div>
    <div class="left-right">
      <div class="some-content">LEFT-RIGHT B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="left-right">
      <div class="some-content">LEFT-RIGHT C</div>
    </div>
    ONLY UP AND DOWN
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was mismatch, sorry. The problem not there.

Comment: I have tried. Only elements works. Container not. But if i click and move on place between green elements, i can swap container up/down... But it is not a solution. I need touch element left to swipe it, and touch element up/down to swap hole container.

Comment: Yes! But you have a scroll. My app is a mobile app (sorry for that! chicken memory) and user must touch on a screen

Comment: I understand but I tried this on mobile and the touch on the screen works just like the scroll and on mobile the scrollbars are gone so it should be usable for you.

Comment: Maybe i am doing something wrong.. Will try once more and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: Please do, if it solves your issue please mark it answered. Otherwise I hope you can find another way to solve it.

Comment: Sure!! I remember about answer mark! Will notify you soon